# how to do carousel image pinch in pinch out(zoom in zoom out) in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, zooming

I have carousel in my application, this application is done by using sencha touch2. As per my requirement,i have to do the ***pinch in pinch out (zoom in zoom out) functionality to the carousel image***. can i achieve this one in sencha touch2 ?. if yes, how to do. i have searched but i didn't get information about this carousel image zoom in zoom out. Can any one tell me how to do this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no pinch-zoom built-in functionality in Sencha Touch 2, but you can use these events : **pinchstart**, **pinch** and **pinchend** from `Ext.dom.Element`

Let's say you have you a container with a image inside :

```
var c = Ext.create('Ext.Container',{...});
```

You can add listeners to it to detect the pinch events :

```
  c.element.on('pinchstart',function(e){
    //...
  },this);

  c.element.on('pinch',function(e){
    //...
  },this);

  c.element.on('pinchend',function(){
    //...
  }, this);
```

I've managed to get something working, but it's not great yet

[Demo](http://titouanvanbelle.fr/GitHub/Sencha/Ext.ux.STCrop/) - [Code](http://titouanvanbelle.fr/GitHub/Sencha/Ext.ux.STCrop/ux/STCrop.js)

Hope this helps